# Running Jmeter tests in Teamcity CI/CD as automation tests

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, continuous-integration, build-verification-test, team-city

I want to add Jmeter tests as build steps in TeamCity CI 
Deployment server. If tests fail, build will not complete. Please advise in details.

I am currently using Jmeter for testing a Rest API running different scenarios/threads on an standalone machine. My intention is to put these tests in our existing CI/CD that has TeamCity. When we deploy a new release, jmeter tests will run as automation tests and if any test fails, then the build will roll back and generate failure reports

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration/

Answer (score 1):

If you can add plugins to TeamCity you can consider using [JMeter plugin for TeamCity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9088-jmeter), it will allow you to set up performance metrics calculation:

[image]

and view the performance statistics:

[image]

There is also possibility to `Check reference values` so you can conditionally mark build as passed or failed depending on [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or other criteria

References:

- [JMeter plugin for TeamCity](https://github.com/jtorgan/jmeter_plugin)
- [How to Run JMeter Tests with TeamCity for Continuous Integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration/)

---

If you cannot add plugins to TeamCity you can just use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for JMeter test, it provides powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem which returns non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) in case if criteria are not met, if TeamCity receives non-zero status code it automatically marks the build as failed.